# Secure delete removed in OSX 10.11

Tags: macos

In OSX 10.10 there was an option to go to `Finder > Empty Trash` or `Finder > Secure Empty Trash`

In OSX 10.11 there now only seems to be an option for `Finder > Empty Trash`

Any ideas way i can get it back ?

Answer (score 1):

It was deliberately removed by Apple, so can't be renabled. There are work-arounds, eg. using srm on the command-line, or third party secure delete products.

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205267

```
Finder

Available for: Mac OS X v10.6.8 and later

Impact: The "Secure Empty Trash" feature may not securely delete files placed in the Trash

Description: An issue existed in guaranteeing secure deletion of Trash files on some systems, such as those with flash storage. This issue was addressed by removing the "Secure Empty Trash" option.

CVE-ID

CVE-2015-5901 : Apple
```

Answer (score -1):

You could sort of get this functionality back by instead deleting the file via the Terminal with the rm utility's option to overwrite a file before it's reference is deleted from the filesystem.

> rm -P filename

"-P  Overwrite regular files before deleting them.  Files are overwritten three times, first with the byte pattern 0xff, then 0x00, and then 0xff again, before they are deleted"

Comment: There is no way to securely erase individual files on SSD drives. This is because their controllers implement wear leveling so that writing a block to an SSD does not overwrite the old block, instead the data is written elsewhere and a pointer is set to the new data. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794612/how-to-securely-wipe-files-from-ssd-drive